# Is there the possibility to force teamcity to execute some command before it pass necessary data to build agent?

Tags: svn, teamcity

Teamcity allow to set up the behavior of build agents. But can I somehow to run some command before the teamcity begin to communicate with build agents after receiving all updates from SVN?

Comment: If you give more detail on the specifics of what you are trying to achieve you will have a better chance of receiving an answer.

Comment: Okay, I would like to run incremental scripts to the database. There is no problem to do it: I set up my **teamcity** in the way that **build agent** receives all script files and executes them.
But I would like to run *.exe file just after **teamcity** receives the last updates from **SVN**. This exe-file should create xls-file which then should be passed to **build agent** (with all scripts). So the problem is to run exe-file (which will create xls-file) because I can't split these two actions: 1) receiving the latest data from **SVN** and 2) passing data to **build agent**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the you can only execute commands inside builds running on an agent.
There are several ways to achieve your goal.

First (simple, but 'dirty'):

- Place your .exe file on the agent(s)
- Insert build step with a coommand line, that will generate xls, on the first place in target build configuration.

So the resulting workflow will look like this:

- Agent receives an updated data from SVN
- Your tool is started and xls file is produced
- Build configuration continues to work

Drawback:

- You'll need to maintain the tool on all agents.

Second (more complicated, but more stable)

- Create new build agent (I'll call it **xls-agent**) on the same host with your tool (e.g., server hosting TeamCity itself)
- Create new build confiuration (I'll call it **xls-producer**) with a single step that will start the tool
- Setup artifact publishing to publish produced xls
- Limit configuration **xls-producer** to the **xls-agent**
- In target build configuration, add two dependencies: snapshot and artifact on **xls-producer**. Make sure "Get artifacts from" is set to "from the same chain"

So the resulting workflow will look like this:

- **xls-agent** runs **xls-producer** with svn revision X
- target configuration downloads xls from **xls-producer** artifacts
- target configuration with exactly the same rev X